# Get content of an element contains a string and select it

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I'm looking for a way to search for a string in a table rows by jquery and get all of that contents and select the element that have it to get the other pieces!
here is the html side:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Tel</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
                                  $allcontacts=$contact->getallcontacts("name",$_SESSION['username']);
                                  if($allcontacts!=null)



                                  foreach($allcontacts as $value){



                                ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="contact-id">
          <?php echo $value[0]; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="contact-name">
          <?php echo $value[1]; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="contact-tell">
          <?php echo $value[2]; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="contact-info">
          <?php echo $value[3]; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="td-actions">
          <a href="?IDD=<?php echo $value[0]." &owner=".$_SESSION['username'];?>">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
          </a>

          <a href="#" class="eb" data-uid="<?php echo $value[0]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#" onclick="" class="se">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="text" class="cs" /><input type="button" value="Search" class="csb"/>
```

here is the script side!

```
$(".csb").click(
  function() {
    var ss = $(".cs").val();
    var farray = $("td:contains(ss)").toArray();
    console.log(farray);
  }
);
```

console gets me an empty array!

Comment: Firstly you need to concatenate the `ss` value in the selector string: `var farray = $("td:contains(" + ss + ")").toArray();`

Comment: @artin Where is the `.csb` class in your html tags? Am I missing something?

Comment: @davidtaylorjr no I missed something! added! thank you!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it worked! but there is a problem ! this method just find that elements start with ss string not that ones contains it! could you explain why I must to concatenate the ss?

Comment: @Artin nope, `:contains` looks within the whole text of the element, although it does have to match case

Answer (score 0):

ok ive tried ur code, obiously without php, so i put plain info. maybe this will help u

```
$(".csb").click(function(){

  var ss = $(".cs").val();
  var farray = new Array(); //define array

  $("tr").removeAttr("style"); //reset all

  if(ss!=""){ //check if isnt empty

    $("td:contains("+ss+")").each(function(){

          $(this).parent().css("background","red"); //select found

          //push to array
          farray.push($(this).parent().find(".contact-id").html());
          farray.push($(this).parent().find(".contact-name").html());
          farray.push($(this).parent().find(".contact-tell").html());
          farray.push($(this).parent().find(".contact-info").html());

    });

  }
  else{ 
    alert("put a text");
  }

  //result
  $("code").html("value search: "+ss);
  $("pre").html("id found: "+farray[0]+"<br>"+
                "name found: "+farray[1]+"<br>"+
                "tel found: "+farray[2]+"<br>"+
                "info found: "+farray[3]);
});
```

this is the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/keejke5e/3/

Comment: Thank you man each() function was helpful for me but in your code it does not search for any string?!!!

Comment: im on my cellphone rightnow, i didnt tested, that was just a tip, ill take a look to the whole code with my laptop

Comment: Thank you so much, it was a big help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add .toArray() as $("td:contains(ss)") returns array. I think you need to check whether you getting `$("td")` element or not. As for I see, according to your code it should find it. So just check `$("td")` and `$("td:contains(ss)")` in your chrome console.